# Why doesn't _com_error derive from std::exception or std::runtime_error?

Tags: c++, exception, com

The Windows [COM support types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/compiler-com-support-classes) (found in comdef.h) include an exception type called [`_com_error`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/com-error-class), which is thrown when a COM error is encountered.

Considering the fact that a `_com_error` is a type which is *thrown*, and considering it embodies the essence of a run-time error; this seems to fall cleanly into the realm of `std::runtime_error`.

Does anyone have any background information, as to why `_com_error` does not inherit from a standard exception type?  The `std::exception` and `std::runtime_error` types have been around a *long* time.

Comment: FYI, `std::runtime_error` was introduced way before C++11.  Were you thinking of `std::system_error`?

Comment: There as no C++ standard yet when `_com_error` was designed.  And always having to map IErrorInfo onto what(), well, ugh.

Comment: @HansPassant they could always have driven from this class retroactively.

Comment: @HansPassant From what I understand, _com_error has ErrorMessage() - which is driven by the HRESULT - and Description(), which is driven by IErrorInfo.  Seems like they could have used the HRESULT-driven mapping

Comment: @DaveS - I think I was just mistaken.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not a Microsoft engineer and therefor my answer is only a guess and not an official answer.

The answer is : ABI compatability.

COM is a technology which allows different technologies, written in different programing languages and run on different platforms to communicate and pass data around.

Visual Basic, C#, JScript, F# and so one know nothing about C++ objects, constructors, desctructors and error hierarchy. Making `_com_error` inherit from `std::exception` and co., will only make it harder for all the technologies to consume this type and use.

Imagine if you wanted to pass that error from a C++ program to a JScript program - the JSCript engine must know how C++ objects look like, and when and how to clean them up.

doing so pretty much cancels the whole point of COM as a "cross technology glue".

You might be asking "so how come this class implements a C++ abstract class? wouldn't that raise the same problems?"
Well, the answer is that the "trick" of the virtual table is an easy technique to marshal to other technologies, and even other programming languages like C# and visual basic use the same model of virtual table for their own uses.

destructors and manual memory management are extremely harder to marshal, especially when the other technologies are garbage collected.

Comment: It just doesn't have anything to do with the ABI. Those C++ helper classes only exist to make writing COM client code in C++ easier. That ball starts rolling with #import, auto-generating code from the type library makes life a wholeheckofalot easier. Giving C++ some parity with languages that support COM in their runtime implementation. Mapping HRESULT error codes onto exceptions is a pretty standard feature.  None of these implementation details are visible across the COM boundary.

Comment: As Hans says, _com_error is only used in C++. It's no use in other languages.